# React native ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

Hi after some time without running my React Native application I received this error

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at stableHash (/Users/danik/App/fitapp2/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stableHash.js:19:8)
    at Object.getCacheKey (/Users/danik/App/fitapp2/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:647:7)
    at getTransformCacheKey (/Users/danik/App/fitapp2/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/getTransformCacheKey.js:32:19)
    at new Transformer (/Users/danik/App/fitapp2/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:180:28)
    at /Users/danik/App/fitapp2/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:58:29 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Node version v12.10.0

```
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.2",
```

OpenSsl V1.1

I already tried with openssl v3, with Node 16, 17, 18 and still this error

Answer (score 0):

Solution was in this

`nvm install v16 && nvm alias default v16 && nvm use v16`

When I tried to switch node version I do it without `nvm alias default v16`

After setting default alias everything working fine